# Не выпадает меню в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Кнопка "Выпадающее меню" должна соответствовать нажатию, при нажатии вообще не реагирует(просто прожимается), возможно, что-то подключено не то, т.к. уроки 2х летней давности, но в силу своей неопытности не могу понять что, помогите пожалуйста.

P.S. Но реагирует на стрелочки вверх  и вниз, при их нажатии выпадает

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Выпадающее меню <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Ссыдка Ссылка Ссылка Ссылка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ссыдка Ссылка Ссылка Ссылка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ссыдка Ссылка Ссылка Ссылка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ссыдка Ссылка Ссылка Ссылка</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>


<link href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css " rel="stylesheet "/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js "></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js "></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так всё работает. Возможно просто нужно было добавить "подключение бутстрапа" в хэд:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css " rel="stylesheet "/>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js "></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js "></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="btn-group pull-right">
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
         Выпадающее меню <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Ссыдка Ссылка Ссылка Ссылка</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссыдка Ссылка Ссылка Ссылка</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссыдка Ссылка Ссылка Ссылка</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ссыдка Ссылка Ссылка Ссылка</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: может в хэде есть еще какие нибуть конфликтующие скрипти?

Comment: Именно ! Благодарю, перенос подключения бутстрапа в голову помог